# Where does all recipe get their on sale data?

Tags: data-request

I had gone to Safeway on Monday to pick up some items, that you posted that were on sale. But they had no idea or how they got posted. Can you please explain so I don't waste my time or has chasing these deals, while trying to make your recipes.

Comment: Sorry Linda, off-topic. Please read [what this site is about](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)